# Get A Python or PhP Script To Process Data On Apache Server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, networking

I'm very new to networking, and backend web development. I have a simple task:

1. Set up an apache2 server on a Debian machine.
2. Host a website on the server.
3. Demonstrate client-server communication.

I've already configured the server, and hosted my website. But I'm having trouble getting a script to do some back-end processing.

It will be something incredibly simple. For example, the webpage has a single form field and a button. The user enters their name for example, and presses the button.

Then the server should run a script (e.g PHP) and output a greeting Hello, `user`.

How can I go about doing this? I need to pass the variable to the php script and then have apache execute the script. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you install php module for apache?

Comment: No I had not. Thank you.